# Android - Reading text File from Application subclass

Tags: java, android, file

I have a method in a subclass of Application that needs to read information from a text file. I have used this method in a subclass of Activity and it worked fine.

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.elements);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String str = reader.readLine();
```

However this gives a null pointer exception if I use this code in the Application subclass.

the text file is in the res/raw folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String readTxt() {

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.elements);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

Works Perfectly, Source : [Display text file in /res/raw](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/display-text-file-in-resraw_01.html)

Comment: Please see the Source http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/display-text-file-in-resraw_01.html this might be helpful

Comment: That only works in an activity. This is in an application subclass.